# Why include guards?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-construction, preprocessor

Include guards, as defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard), are used to prevent loading the same code twice at compilation.

Why can't my compiler (GCC) detect that it is loading the same code twice and have a sensible default behaviour?

Comment: Some people do intentionally include the same file twice (where the second inclusion has a real effect). This works, this is valid, so changing this would break existing code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Simply because you might have wanted the compiler to load that file twice.

Remember, that `#include` simply loads a file and puts its contents in the place of the directive. This file might be a header file, but may be useful and frequently used piece of source code as well.

Most modern compilers react to `#pragma once` doing exactly what you want them to. Remember though, that this is a compiler extension not included in the language specification and it is generally a good idea to stick to include guards - you'll be certain, that it works on every compiler and in any circumstances.

Comment: Re `#pragma once`: it's not 100% reliable, so you still need include guards.

Comment: @JamesKanze - What do you want to say by "not 100% reliable"?

Comment: That there are cases when it is impossible to detect whether two includes refer to the same file or not.  They don't occur in simple, stand alone systems (at least not that I know of), but can (and in practice do, albeit rarely) occur once you start networking.  The committee actually discussed making `#pragma once` standard, and rejected it because it wasn't (reliably) implementable.

Comment: @JamesKanze Ok, may be worth noticing.

Comment: @JamesKanze - Oh, so you mean there could be confusion between the same file accessed via different paths? `#include "test.h" #include "c:\source\test.h" #include "c:/symbolic/link/to/test.h"`. I can see that could be an issue...

Comment: @Roddy Not just from symbolic links---at least under Unix, there are ways of working around this.  But when an imported file system is mounted at two different places.  (Strangely enough, this happens more often than one might expect.)

Answer (score 12):

> Why can't my compiler (GCC) detect that it is loading the same code twice

It can (or, pedantically, the preprocessor that deals with header inclusion can). Instead of using include guards, you could use a non-standard but widely supported extension

```
#pragma once
```

to indicate that this header should only be included once.

> and have a sensible default behaviour?

The language doesn't specify this behaviour by default, largely because the language dates back to times when tracking included headers could be prohibitively expensive, and partly because  sometimes you do want to include a header more than once. For example, the standard `<assert.h>` header can be reincluded with or without `NDEBUG` defined to change the behaviour of the `assert` macro.

Comment: `#pragma once` is a preprocessor feature though, not a compiler feature.

Comment: @datenwolf: Indeed, if you want to regard the first few translation stages as "preprocessing".

Comment: @datenwolf Isn't the preprocessor *a part* of the compiler?

Comment: Uh, those are called "preprocessor" for a reason. And a number of programs actually use the C preprocessor without the compiler for their own text substitution needs. (like for example the Xrdb resource loader).

Comment: @Spook: No, not really; it's part of the compiler toolchain of course, but the proprocessor usually runs as a separate process and in many compiler suits is actually contained in a different executable.

Comment: @datenwolf: That's irrelevant to this question about basic compilation, where all that matters is that it's part of the translation process, which we might as well loosely call "compilation", but I've added a note that might keep some pedants happy.

Comment: @datenwolf By whom?  The standard specifies a total of 9 steps in program translation.  The term "preprocessor" is a colloquial expression (not exact) for the first 6.

Comment: @datenwolf What compiler runs the preprocessor as a separate process?  (Not that it matters, of course.  g++, and probably a lot of other compilers, run the front-end, the optimizer and the back-end as separate processes.)

Answer (score 9):

Because there are bizarre edge cases where re-including a file is useful.

Contrived ugly example: Suppose you had an `#include` file `mymin.h` like this:

```
// mymin.h : ugly "pseudo-template" hack
MINTYPE min(MINTYPE a, MINTYPE b)
{
   return (a < b) ? a : b;
}
```

You could then do something like this:

```
#define MINTYPE int
#include "mymin.h"

#define MINTYPE double
#include "mymin.h"
```

Now, you have two overloads of `min` for different types, and a good candidate for http://thedailywtf.com/.   Who needs templates? ;-)

Note that lots of modern preprocessors support `#pragma once`, which is a much nicer way of achieving the same effect as include guards. However, it's unfortunately non-standard.

Comment: in this case why don't `#define` both A and B before including the header?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc _ I did warn it was contrived...  It's just to illustrate that re-`include`ing a file could have a different effect each time.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc - I've changed the "example". but this is still a case of "don't try this at home".

Comment: Is it bad that I actually really like this way of making "templates" ? That said I think you could make it a bit more safe by defining an include guard based on each type (`MINTYPE_H_int` for example).

Answer (score 4):

> Why can't my compiler (GCC) detect that it is loading the same code twice and have a sensible default behaviour?

Because it's not the compiler doing the include processing. It's done by the preprocessor which is essentially a text transformation engine. And for text transformation engine it can make perfect sense if the same include appears multiple times when processing a piece of text.

Let sink this in for a moment: The compiler does not process `#include`s. This is what makes it impossible to make sensible decisions on symbol redefinitions by the compiler.

Other languages implement modules as a part of the language, and in those languages things are not processed as a text substitution and the compiler actually has knowledge about the import semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Include guards protect against symbol redefinition and including the same files multiple times.

The compiler needs this mechanism because for obvious reasons, it does not include a mechanism to analyze and decide which code version to consider. Think of what would happen if the same function signature in two different header files only the return type is different.

Assuming the content is exactly the same only it's included from multiple headers, The compiler would require extra computing power and memory to keep track of the code it already included.

So it would be  error prone and inneficient

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't my compiler (GCC) detect that it is loading the same code twice and have a sensible default behaviour?

Because then it wouldn't be a C compiler.  The language is specified such that `#include` creates a textual transclusion, and doing something different to the specification would break valid code.

The obvious follow-up question, "could we change the C Standard?" still has to find some way to avoid the same breakage of existing valid code.

One thing a compiler *could* legitimately do is to emit a *warning* when a non-empty (after processing `#ifdef` and the like) file is multiply included without some indicator that it's intentional.  If you're sufficiently motivated, perhaps you could prepare a suitable patch for your favourite compiler(s)?

BTW, you'll find that the problem gets very hard as soon as you have to come up with a good robust definition of "same code".

Answer (score -2):

Even if compiler decides to do that, it needs to keep track of huge number of files, and many times (as commented by itwasntpete), compiler has no way to distinguish between actual code and header file.

Comment: Makes no sense. It's got to keep track of the same number of #defines for the header guards...