# Redefinition of a class in C++

Tags: c++, class, header, friend-function

I'm new to C++ and stuck in a problem with an Error, called

"Semantic Issue: Redefinition of 'B' cB.h".

I have two classes, A and B, where cA should handle an Object of cB by reference and one friend function of cA, fExample. This is what the code looks like:

**.h file cA:**

```
#include "cB.h"

class A{
  int val1, val2;
public:
  friend void fExample(int, cB &);
};
```

**.h file cB:**

```
class B{
  int val1, val2;
public:
  void set_val1(int);
};
```

**.cpp file cB:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cB.h"
using namespace std;

void B::set_val1(int tVal){
  val1 = tVal;
}
```

For me, it seems there is no way of working with the cB-object by reference with a friend function of cA. I would know some workarounds, but that's not my intention, I want to learn how to handle this problem the right way.

So thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: Redefinition of `B`? Where's `B`?

Comment: Sorry, there should be 'class B', not 'class cB'. i've miswritten it in the code above.

Comment: Missing include guards?

Comment: No, I haven't included guards.

Comment: In the header file for a you do not need to include the header for b. Instead forward declare b. Also add include guards.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21090041/why-include-guards

Comment: I thought only pointers were allowed when using forward declaration?

Comment: @DonMan references are allowed as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of error often happen due to missing include guards. The Simplest way is:

```
#ifndef HEADER_NAME
#define HEADER_NAME
```

You may also use [#pragma once](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once)

Comment: While widely supported, `#pragma once` (like any other *pragma*) is non-standard, include guards are a better alternative.