# C++ Makefile, Redefinition of class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, makefile

So I'm trying to make a very simple makefile for my program. The program has 6 classes with inheritance and I have created separate .h and .cpp files for each of them.

The problem I am having is that when I run the makefile I get an error telling me:

```
In file included from Items.h:2:0,
             from GraphicsCards.h:3,
             from GraphicsCards.cpp:1:
Orders.h:5:7: error: redefinition of ‘class Orders’
Orders.h:5:7: error: previous definition of ‘class Orders’
make: *** [GraphicsCards.o] Error 1
```

Below is my Makefile:

```
# all - compile the program if any source files have changed
all: Orders.o Customers.o Items.o GraphicsCards.o Proccessors.o HardDrives.o driver.o
g++ Orders.o Customers.o Items.o GraphicsCards.o Proccessors.o HardDrives.o driver.o -o program

# Orders.o
Orders.o: Orders.cpp Orders.h
g++ -c Orders.cpp -o Orders.o

# Customers.o
Customers.o: Customers.cpp Customers.h
g++ -c Customers.cpp -o Customers.o

# Items.o
Items.o: Items.cpp Items.h
g++ -c Items.cpp -o Items.o

# GraphicsCards.o
GraphicsCards.o: GraphicsCards.cpp GraphicsCards.h
g++ -c GraphicsCards.cpp -o GraphicsCards.o

# Proccessors.o
Proccessors.o: Proccessors.cpp Proccessors.h
g++ -c Proccessors.cpp -o Proccessors.o

# HardDrives.o
HardDrives.o: HardDrives.cpp HardDrives.h
g++ -c HardDrives.cpp -o HardDrives.o

# driver.o
driver.o: driver.cpp Orders.h Customers.h Items.h GraphicsCards.h Proccessors.h HardDrives.h
g++ -c driver.cpp -o driver.o

# clean - delete the compiled version of your program and
# any object files or other temporary files created during compilation.
clean:
rm -f *.o program
```

As an example this is what my GraphicsCards.h file looks like:

```
#include <string>
#include "Orders.h"
#include "Items.h"

using namespace std;

class GraphicsCards: protected Items
{
    private:
    int speed;
    string model;
    int memory;
};
```

Also all of my x.cpp files have #include "x.h" as their first line

I'm fairly new to C++ coding so even if you cant help me with my question any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using [include guards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21090041/why-include-guards?s=2|4.9890) properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be missing inclusion guards in your header files.

Try adding

```
#pragma once
```

as the first line of each header file

Note that the #pragma once is a compiler specific extension, but it is well supported and works on all major and most minor c++ compilers

Comment: Wow it worked! Thanks, So what does that line actually do?

Comment: The #include statement actually just copies the file content, so including the same file twice creates multiple copies (and in your case, class definitions) of the content of this file. To circumvent this, you need so called includsion guards. The correct way, would be to #define a file specific token (like #define FOO_H_) and check if its defines inside the file. The #pragma once directive is a shorthand which is not actually part of the standard but you will be hard pressed to find a compiler not supporting this