# c++ error with makefile compile, could not convert main()::

Tags: c++, makefile

I am working on this project right now and this is my first time with a makefile.

The error that I get is:

```
HW1.cpp:45:55: error: could not convert ‘Student1’ from ‘main()::Student’ to ‘Student’
```

Main File:

```
#include "header.h"
#include "function.h"

main()
{

    int input = 0;
    bool loop = 1;

    #include "list.cpp"

    ResetArray(arrayCou, arrayStu);

    while (loop)
    {
        cout << "cmd> ";
        cin >> input;
        switch (input)
        {
            case 1:
                AddCourse(&Course1, arrayCou);
                break;
            case 2:
                AddStudent(&Student1, arrayStu);
                break;
            case 3:
                AddStuCourse(&Student1, &Course1, arrayStu, arrayCou);
                break;
            case 4:
                AddGrade(&Student1, &Course1, arrayStu, arrayCou);
                break;
            case 5:
                PrintCourse(&Student1, &Course1, arrayStu, arrayCou);
                break;
            case 6:
                PrintStudent(&Student1, &Course1, arrayStu, arrayCou);
                break;
            case 7:
                PrintStuCourse(&Student1, &Course1, arrayStu, arrayCou);
                break;
            case 8:
                AvgStuCourse(&Student1, &Course1, arrayStu, arrayCou);
                break;
            case 9:
                loop = 0;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Function Declaration:

```
#include "header.h"

void ResetArray(Course arrayCou[][101][5], Student arrayStu[][3]);
void AddCourse(Course Course1, Course arrayCou[][101][5]);
void AddStudent(Student Student1, Student arrayStu[][3]);
void AddStuCourse(Student Student1, Course Course1, Student arrayStu[][3], Course arrayCou[][101][5]);
void AddGrade(Student Student1, Course Course1, Student arrayStu[][3], Course arrayCou[][101][5]);
void PrintCourse(Student Student1, Course Course1, Student arrayStu[][3], Course arrayCou[][101][5]);
void PrintStudent(Student Student1, Course Course1, Student arrayStu[][3], Course arrayCou[][101][5]);
void PrintStuCourse(Student Student1, Course Course1, Student arrayStu[][3], Course arrayCou[][101][5]);
void AvgStuCourse(Student Student1, Course Course1, Student arrayStu[][3], Course arrayCou[][101][5]);
```

Header File:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const int MAXSIZE = 101;

struct Student
{
    string ID;
    string name;
    string majors;
};

struct Course
{
    string ID;
    string title;
    string department;
    double grade;
};

Student arrayStu[101][3];
Course arrayCou[101][101][5];

Course Course1;
Student Student1;
```

The function definitions are really long so I didn't want to include all of it, but is there any way to fix the makefile? It says the same error for every use of Student1 or Course1 in the main function.

Comment: Should be `int main()`

Comment: You forgot the return type on main.

Comment: BTW, show your `Makefile` or at least the compilation command

Comment: `#include "list.cpp"` - including a `cpp` inside a function? Really?

Comment: BTW it seems like your header file doesn't have [include guards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21090041/why-include-guards). If so, add them before you try anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`main()::Student` means your `Student` structure is declared inside `main`. `struct` declarations inside functions are very uncommonly used, and in your case it's a mistake. It is caused by

```
#include "list.cpp"
```

in your `main` function.

You should declare the `struct` outside your function. To do so, move your `#include` directive so it's before `main`:

```
#include "function.h"
#include "list.cpp"
...
int main()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: On the other hand, you should probably never `#include` a .cpp file.

Answer (score -1):

all the functions must have return type in c/c++ ( if nothing is being returned then it should be void ) , and main function must return an integer so that, OS can read the returned number and determine whether program executed successfully or not. ( if you return non 0 number as return in main function OS thinks that program did not execute normally )

So the code should be as following

```
#include "header.h"
#include "function.h"

int main()
{

    int input = 0;
    bool loop = 1;

    #include "list.cpp"

    ResetArray(arrayCou, arrayStu);

    while (loop)
    {
        cout << "cmd> ";
        cin >> input;
        switch (input)
        {
            case 1:
                AddCourse(&Course1, arrayCou);
                break;
            case 2:
                AddStudent(&Student1, arrayStu);
                break;
            case 3:
                AddStuCourse(&Student1, &Course1, arrayStu, arrayCou);
                break;
            case 4:
                AddGrade(&Student1, &Course1, arrayStu, arrayCou);
                break;
            case 5:
                PrintCourse(&Student1, &Course1, arrayStu, arrayCou);
                break;
            case 6:
                PrintStudent(&Student1, &Course1, arrayStu, arrayCou);
                break;
            case 7:
                PrintStuCourse(&Student1, &Course1, arrayStu, arrayCou);
                break;
            case 8:
                AvgStuCourse(&Student1, &Course1, arrayStu, arrayCou);
                break;
            case 9:
                loop = 0;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: all the functions must have return type in c/c++ ( if nothing is being returned then it should be void ) , and main function must return an integer so that, OS can read the returned number and determine whether program executed successfully or not. ( if you return non 0 number as return in main function OS thinks that program did not execute normally )

Comment: It would be useful if you explicitly state the error that exists in the original code.

Comment: @meetthakkar You should add to the answer in text what you did.

Comment: @meetthakkar That really needs to be in your answer