# Creating a template class for a pair that returns a pair

Tags: c++, class, templates

the code isn't working and I'm not sure where I've gone wrong any help would be much appreciated this is the details of the assignment create a class template by writing a template for a class named "Pair". This class will represent a pair of data members of a type that is parameterized in the template definition. For example, you could have a Pair of integers, a Pair of doubles, etc.

```
/* so I'm trying to implement this driver this is the driver.cpp file and
 * I'm trying to do it with a template class */

int main()
{
   Pair<char> letters('a', 'd');
   cout << "\nThe first letter is: " << letters.getFirst();
   cout << "\nThe second letter is: " << letters.getSecond();

   cout << endl;
   cin.get();
}

//this is my .h file code
template <class T>
class Pair
{
   private:
      T first;
      T second;
   public:
      Pair(const T, const T);
      T getFirst();
      T getSecond();
};

//this is my Pair.cpp
#include "Pair.h"


template<class T>
Pair<T>::Pair(const T first, const T second)
{
   return first, second;
}

template<class T>
inline T Pair<T>::getFirst()
{
   return first;
}

template<class T>
inline T Pair<T>::getSecond()
{
   return second;
}
```

Comment: The constructor should not return the values, but set the member variables to the parameter values. A bit tricky when you use the same names...

Comment: *the code isn't working* doesn't explain much. Are you seeing problems at compile time, run time? What's the nature of the problem? Post messages from compiler if there is a compile time problem. Post the output if there is a run time problem.

Comment: Off topic: recommend a read of [Why include guards?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21090041/why-include-guards)

Comment: I'm getting three errors that say unresolved external symbol

Answer (score 1):

There are two distinct problems with you code.

First, you only have the declaration of the member functions in `Pair.h` and the definitions in a seperate `Pair.cpp` file. While this works for regular functions, it doesn't work for templates (see [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)), as mentioned already by Guillaume Racicot in a comment to your question.

The second issue is that your constructor isn't initializing the data members of your`Pair` class, but instead returns the second argument you passed to it, even though a constructor can't have a return value.

To fix this you need to change the definition of the constructor to

```
template <typename T>
Pair<T>::Pair(T fst, T snd)
    : first{std::move(fst)},
      second{std::move(snd)} {
}
```

The calls to `std::move` are not necessary here, but this is the idiomatic way to move values into variables. If you were to only do `first{fst}` you'd end up making one additional copy instead of a move, which isn't that big of a deal for primitive types such as `int` or `float`, but if you were to create a pair of large objects (e.g. two 1000 element vectors) then this can make a huge difference.

After applying both these changes and adding [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) you should end up with a single `Pair.h` file

```
#ifndef PAIR_H
#define PAIR_H

template <class T>
class Pair
{
   private:
      T first;
      T second;
   public:
      Pair(T, T);
      T getFirst();
      T getSecond();
};

template<class T>
Pair<T>::Pair(T fst, T snd)
    : first{std::move(fst)},
      second{std::move(snd)}
{
}

template<class T>
T Pair<T>::getFirst()
{
   return first;
}

template<class T>
T Pair<T>::getSecond()
{
   return second;
}
#endif
```

Comment: this was super helpful, thanks for taking the time to write it out.

Answer (score -1):

here is simple pair.h template

```
// Pair.h
// template for a pair of items of arbitrary types

#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

template <typename S, typename T>
class Pair
   {
      public:
               Pair();
               Pair(S,T);
               Pair(Pair &);
               ~Pair();
               const Pair &operator=(const Pair &other);

               string toString();

               S* getFirst();
               T* getSecond();
              int getPairCount();

               void setFirst(S);
               void setSecond(T);

      private:
               S *f;
               T *s;
               static int count;

   };

template <typename S, typename T>
int Pair<S,T>::count=0;

// 0-parameter constructor
template <typename S, typename T>
Pair<S,T>::Pair()
   {
      f = NULL;
      s = NULL;
      count++;
   }

// 2-param constructor
template <typename S, typename T>
Pair<S,T>::Pair(S x, T y)
   {
      f = new S;  *f = x;
      s = new T;  *s = y;
      count++;
   }


// get first element in pointer
template <typename S, typename T>
S* Pair<S,T>::getFirst()
   {
      if (f!=NULL)
         {  S *tmp = new S;
            *tmp = *f;
            return tmp;
         }
      else
         return NULL;
   }

// get second element in pointer
template <typename S, typename T>
T* Pair<S,T>::getSecond()
   {
      if (s!=NULL)
         {
            T *tmp = new T;
            *tmp = *s;
            return tmp;
         }
      else
         return NULL;
   }

// set first element
template <typename S, typename T>
void Pair<S,T>::setFirst(S x)
   {
      if (f==NULL)
         f = new S;
      *f = x;
   }

// set second element
template <typename S, typename T>
void Pair<S,T>::setSecond(T y)
   {
      if (s==NULL)
         s = new T;
      *s = y;
   }

// make a string representation
template <typename S, typename T>
string Pair<S,T>::toString()
   {
      stringstream ss;
      ss<<"(";
      if (f==NULL)
         ss<<"NULL";
      else
         ss<<(*f);
      ss<<",";
      if (s==NULL)
         ss<<"NULL";
      else
         ss<<(*s);
      ss<<")";
      return ss.str();
   }

// keep count
template <typename S, typename T>
int Pair<S,T>::getPairCount(){
    return count;}

//copy constructor
template <typename S, typename T>
Pair<S,T>::Pair(Pair &other)
{
f = NULL; s = NULL;
    if(other.f != NULL)
    f = new S(*other.f);

    if(other.s != NULL)
    s = new T(*other.s);

    count++;
}
//destructor

template <typename S, typename T>
Pair<S,T>::~Pair()
{
    if(f != NULL)
    delete f;

    if(s != NULL)
    delete s;

    f = NULL;
    s = NULL;

    count--;
}

//deep assignment

template <typename S, typename T>
const Pair<S,T> & Pair<S,T>::operator=(const Pair<S,T> &other)
{
    if(this != &other)
    {
        if(f != NULL)
        delete f;

        if(s != NULL)
        delete s;

        f = NULL; s = NULL;

        if(other.f != NULL)
        f = new S(*other.f);

        if(other.s != NULL)
        s = new T(*other.s);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Eww, pointers...

Comment: LOL, if you are working with templates you should have an idea over pointers. try reading the code, it will make sense

Comment: Pointers are just uncalled for in this situation.  If you really want those semantics, you should at least use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::optional` (C++17).

Comment: @aschepler i simply pasted a header file that i had at hand as reference for her, i also believe she is doing this for a class and if tats a case i believe she should work with a simple good old pointer before learning different options that are there

Comment: @dirty_feri Why not work with simple good old values before learning about owning raw pointers?

Comment: You make it sound like `std::unique_ptr` is an advanced topic.  But in modern C++, using `new` and `delete` is an advanced topic, and to be avoided.

Comment: To answer both comments, to be honest this is how i was taught and what i am use to, you guys are also correct

Comment: I received a down vote for an answer that works and acomplishes the intended job, however no one else has introduced an answer

Comment: @dirty_feri I downvoted this answer for many reasons, the main one was already stated in the comments: Use of owning raw pointers. Alycia stated she is doing this as part of an assignment, so presumably is still learning C++. As stated by aschepler, `new` and `delete` are not something a beginner should deal with, and you agreed with that sentiment. I feel we as a community shouldn't teach others things that are now considered bad practice, there already are enough bad tutorials out there. I recommend watching Kate Gregorys talk [Stop teaching C](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk).

Comment: The second issue is that you completely ignored the code that was posted by Alycia. There are two simple fixes to the code in the question that make it work: Move the definitions to the header file and fix the constructor. Instead you provided a completely different implementation that doesn't even fit the requirements - the question states that `Pair` should implement a homogeneous pair, not a heterogeneous one.

Answer (score -1):

The constructor should not return anything. Its function is to initialize the object by means of the variables passed as parameters.

```
template<class T>
Pair<T>::Pair(const T fst, const T scd) : first(fst), second(scd)
{}
```

Comment: Corrected by applying new syntax