# adding classes to a vector of the same type results in error. is deprecated

Tags: c++, class, vector, types

I'm trying to create a custom type of class object and i would i like to add to a vector.
how it's done?

this is the code of the class and the issues it trows at me.
the class on it's own works as expected, but when trying to add these to a vector!

edit: uploaded the total code with all the comments and stuff.

```
#ifndef TRIPLE_H
#define TRIPLE_H

#include <iostream>

#include <sstream>

#include <initializer_list>

// https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

template <typename S, typename T, typename R>
class Triple
   {
      public:
               Triple();
               Triple(S, T, R);
               Triple(Triple &);
               ~Triple();
               const Triple &operator=(const Triple &other);
               //bool operator> (const TRIPLE &lhs, const TRIPLE &rhs);
               //bool operator> (const TRIPLE &lhs);
               //bool operator>(const TRIPLE &right) const;

               string toString();
               string getPerimeter();
               int getPeri();

               S* getFirst();
               S  getFirstvalue(); ///////////////
               T* getSecond();

               void set(S,T,R);

               int getPairCount();

               void setFirst(S);
               void setSecond(T);

      private:
               S *first;
               T *second;
               R *third;
               int *perimeter;
               static int count_of_triples;

   };

template <typename S, typename T, typename R>
int Triple<S, T, R>::count_of_triples=0;

// 0-parameter constructor
template <typename S, typename T, typename R>
Triple<S, T, R>::Triple() : first(NULL), second(NULL), third(NULL), perimeter(0)
   {
      //f = NULL;
      //s = NULL;
      count_of_triples++;
   }

// 2-param constructor
template <typename S, typename T, typename R>
Triple<S, T, R>::Triple(S x, T y, R z) // : first(x), second(y), third(z), perimeter(x + y + z)
{
    first = new S;
    *first = x;
    second = new T;
    *second = y;
    third = new R;
    *third= y;
    perimeter = new int;
    //*perimeter = z;
    //std::cout << "perimeter: " << (x + y + z) << end;
    *perimeter = (x + y + z);
    count_of_triples++;
}

template <typename S, typename T, typename R>
S Triple<S, T, R>::getFirstvalue(){
    if (first!=NULL){
//        if(*first == 0){
//            std::cout << "error" << endl;
//        }
//        else{
//            std::cout << "all ok" << endl;
//        }
        return *first;
    }
    else
        //return NULL; // warning: converting to non-pointer type 'int' from NULL
        return 0;
}

template <typename S, typename T, typename R>
string Triple<S, T, R>::toString()
   {
      stringstream ss;
      ss<<"(";
      if (first==NULL)
         ss<<"NULL";
      else
         ss<<(*first);
      ss<<",";
      if (second==NULL)
         ss<<"NULL";
      else
         ss<<(*second);
      ss<<",";
      if (third==NULL)
         ss<<"NULL";
      else
         ss<<(*third);
      ss<<")";
      return ss.str();
   }

template <typename S, typename T, typename R>
string Triple<S, T, R> ::getPerimeter(){
    stringstream ss;
    ss<<"(";
    if (perimeter==NULL)
       ss<<"NULL";
    else
       ss<<(*perimeter);
    ss<<")";
    return ss.str();
}

template <typename S, typename T, typename R>
int Triple<S, T, R> ::getPeri(){

    return  *perimeter;
}

template <typename S, typename T, typename R>
Triple<S, T, R> ::~Triple()
{
    if(first != NULL)
    delete first;

    if(second != NULL)
    delete second;

    if(third != NULL)
    delete third;

    if(perimeter != NULL)
    delete perimeter;

    first = NULL;
    second = NULL;
    third = NULL;
    perimeter = NULL;

    count_of_triples--;
}

template <typename S, typename T, typename R>
int Triple<S, T, R>::getPairCount(){
    return count_of_triples;
}

template <typename S, typename T, typename R>
void Triple<S, T, R>::set(S x, T y, R z){
    if (first ==__null)
    first = new S;
    *first = x;
    std::cout << "first:" << *first << endl;

    if (second ==__null)
    second = new S;
    *second = y;
    std::cout << "second:" << *second << endl;

    if (third ==__null)
        third = new R;
    *third = z;
    std::cout << "third:" << *third << endl;

    if (perimeter ==__null)
        perimeter = new int;
    *perimeter = (x + y + z);
}

template <typename S, typename T, typename R>
const Triple<S, T, R> &Triple<S, T, R>::operator=(const Triple<S, T, R> &other){

}

template <typename S, typename T, typename R>
bool operator>(Triple<S, T, R> &lhs, Triple<S, T, R> &rhs){
    return lhs.getPeri() > rhs.getPeri();
}

template <typename S, typename T, typename R>
bool operator<(Triple<S, T, R> &lhs, Triple<S, T, R> &rhs){
    return lhs.getPeri() < rhs.getPeri();
}
    

#endif // TRIPLE_H
```

main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

//#include <utility>

#include "Triple.h"



    typedef vector<Triple<int, int, int>> triVector;
    
    int main(){
    
    
        Triple<int, int, int> triple;// {1,2,3};
        triple.set(1,2,3);
        std::cout << " ***** " << triple.toString() << endl;
        std::cout << "get perimeter " << triple.getPerimeter() << endl;
        std::cout << "get count " << triple.getPairCount() << endl;
    
        Triple<int, int, int> *triple2 = new Triple<int, int, int>(1,2,5);
        //TRIPLE<int, int, int> *triple2 = new TRIPLE<int, int, int>({1,2,1});
        std::cout << " ***** " << triple2->toString() << endl;
        std::cout << "get perimeter " << triple2->getPerimeter() << endl;
        std::cout << "get count " << triple2->getPairCount() << endl;
    
        Triple<int, int, int> triple3;// {1,2,3};
        triple3.set(1,2,2);
    
        if(triple < *triple2){
            std::cout << "true" << endl;
        }
        else{
            std::cout << "not true" << endl;
        }
    
        std::cout << triple.getFirstvalue() << endl;
    
    
    
        triVector temp;
        temp.push_back(*triple2);
    //    temp.push_back(triple);
    //    temp.push_back(triple3);
    
        for(auto i : temp){
            std::cout << "peri: " << i.getPeri() << endl;
        }
    
        std::cout << "-----------------------------------------" << endl;
        //sort(temp.begin(), temp.end());
    
    //    for(auto i : temp){
    //        std::cout << "peri: " << i.getPeri() << endl;
    //    }
    
    //    std::cout << "-----------------------------------------" << endl;
    
        return 0;
    }
```

error:

```
/usr/include/c++/9/ext/new_allocator.h:145: error: binding reference of type ‘Triple<int, int, int>&’ to ‘const Triple<int, int, int>’ discards qualifiers
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/c++allocator.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/string:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from ../Pair_template/main.cpp:14:
/usr/include/c++/9/ext/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of ‘void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = Triple<int, int, int>; _Args = {const Triple<int, int, int>&}; _Tp = Triple<int, int, int>]’:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/alloc_traits.h:482:2:   required from ‘static void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::construct(std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::allocator_type&, _Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = Triple<int, int, int>; _Args = {const Triple<int, int, int>&}; _Tp = Triple<int, int, int>; std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::allocator_type = std::allocator<Triple<int, int, int> >]’
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1189:30:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = Triple<int, int, int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<Triple<int, int, int> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = Triple<int, int, int>]’
../Pair_template/main.cpp:91:28:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/ext/new_allocator.h:145:20: error: binding reference of type ‘Triple<int, int, int>&’ to ‘const Triple<int, int, int>’ discards qualifiers
  145 |  noexcept(noexcept(::new((void *)__p)
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  146 |        _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...)))
      |        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Because vector reallocates its contents, vector's contents must be compliant with the Rule Of 3. The shown custom template is not. You must implement a proper copy constructor and an assignment operator in your template class.

Comment: Usually a copy constructor does not modify its parameter.

Comment: Typo(s) `Triple(Triple &) ~Triple();` ?  And the next two lines.  How do we know this is the real code we should be looking at ?  And _"...debugger halts at: ~Triple()..."_ nope it's the compiler says it can't compile the program.

Comment: I was tempted to fix the obvious syntax error in the posted code during the format-fix, namely the missing `;` after the declaration of the non-standard copy-ctor before the dtor. I decided not to. Nine years on SO and I'm still bewildered how copy/pasting supposedly problem reproducing code somehow introduces "typos". Gremlins.

Comment: `first == __null` -- What is `__null`?  Identifiers with leading underscores are reserved for the implementation.   Second, `std::tuple<S, T, R> m_tuple;` instead of all of those pointers reduces the code you have now by more than half.

Comment: [Using std::tuple](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3fb4cbe6ba70b06f).  Your current code has potential memory leaks and all sorts of other issues -- might as well show you something that achieves what you're trying to code, but a lot simpler.

Comment: @RichardCritten the real code is slightly larger, to prevent a long page i just pasted the "working" code and what causes the problem.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie if your hold down "alt" and click on NULL it leads to "stddef.h", indicating it's a definition: #define NULL __null,  i toke the code from here " https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43565391/creating-a-template-class-for-a-pair-that-returns-a-pair " and elaborated some more on it as an exercise.

Comment: @WhozCraig sorry, i wanted to prevent a long page and only copy and pasted the part that is causing the problem, now i pasted the total code.

Comment: @WhozCraig, i recenty picked up the wire again and left off where i dropped it years ago.

Comment: I don't suppose your toolchain is C++17 compliant, is it?

Comment: @WhozCraig, i have C++17 installed, but so far not used it and use C++11. for online coding competitions.

Comment: I only ask because `std::optional` seems like it would eliminate (a) about 70% of your code, and (b) 100% of your problems with this.

Comment: @WhozCraig HackerRank gives you C++14, max, but i would like to see it working in C++11.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the credit goes to you, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration of the class is wrong:

```
Triple(Triple &) ~Triple();
```

Should be:

```
TRIPLE(TRIPLE&);
~TRIPLE();
```

Your class is very weird and seems to be very heavily inspired by Java. No need for all those pointers and the standard `std::tuple` is probably a good fit for what you're trying to do .

Comment: i toke it from here ' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43565391/creating-a-template-class-for-a-pair-that-returns-a-pair ' and expanded it as an exercise, that's not the problem, it's correct here in the compiler, copy and paste error that slipped through, thanx though.

Comment: @NaturalDemon After editing your question, it is now significantly different.

Comment: it's the same, but now with the parts included i left out to prevent a long page.

Answer (score 0):

the credit goes to @PaulMcKenzie

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

template <typename S, typename T, typename R>
class TRIPLE
{
public:
    TRIPLE();
    TRIPLE(S, T, R);
    void set(S, T, R);
    S getFirstvalue();
    std::string toString();

private:
    std::tuple<S, T, R> m_tuple;
};

// 0-parameter constructor
template <typename S, typename T, typename R>
TRIPLE<S, T, R>::TRIPLE() : m_tuple{} {}

// 3-param constructor
template <typename S, typename T, typename R>
TRIPLE<S, T, R>::TRIPLE(S x, T y, R z) : m_tuple{x, y, x} {}

template <typename S, typename T, typename R>
void TRIPLE<S, T, R>::set(S x, T y, R z) 
{
    m_tuple = {x, y, z};
}

template <typename S, typename T, typename R>
S TRIPLE<S, T, R>::getFirstvalue()
{
    return std::get<0>(m_tuple);
}

template <typename S, typename T, typename R>
std::string TRIPLE<S, T, R>::toString()
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "(" << std::get<0>(m_tuple) << "," << std::get<1>(m_tuple) 
            << "," << std::get<2>(m_tuple) <<  ")";
    return ss.str();
}

typedef std::vector<TRIPLE<int, int, int>> triVector;

int main()
{
    TRIPLE<int, int, int> triple;
    triple.set(1, 2, 3);

    TRIPLE<int, int, int> triple2;
    triple2.set(1, 2, 3);

    TRIPLE<int, int, int> triple3;
    triple3.set(1, 2, 3);

    TRIPLE<int, int, int> triple4;
    triple4.set(1, 2, 3);

    triVector temp;

    temp.push_back(triple2);
    temp.push_back(triple);
    temp.push_back(triple3);

    for (auto i : temp)
    {
        std::cout << "first value: " << i.getFirstvalue() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```