# c programming, create dynamic array which stores pointers, struc

Tags: c, struct, malloc

So my problem is kinda annoying. I have to create a struc called vector, which holds a string ~ array of chars. For later use. What Ive written so far:

```
vector.h
// forward declare structs and bring them from the tag namespace to the ordi$
typedef struct Vector Vector;

// actually define the structs
struct Vector {
    int SortPlace;
    char LineContent[100];
};

vector.c
// Initialize a vector to be empty.
// Pre: v != NULL
void Vector_ctor(Vector *v) {
    assert(v); // In case of no vector v
    (*v).SortPlace = 0;
    (*v).LineContent[100] = {""};
}
```

My error message is:

```
vector.c: In function ‘Vector_ctor’:
vector.c:13:24: error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
  v->LineContent[100] = {""};
```

Since im new to c programming im kinda lost. Basically i want to create a vector with no content.

Any help would be appreciated.
Greetings

Comment: *`(*v).foo`* *~>* `v->foo` (`(*v).foo` is not wrong, but it's awkward to read)

Comment: In `vector.c`: `#include "vector.h"`

Comment: in `vector.h` enclose your code in `#ifndef VECTOR_H_INCLUDED` newline `#define VECTOR_H_INCLUDED` and `#endif`. See [Why include guards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21090041/why-include-guards)

Comment: Hi Swordfish, I have included vector.h and did enclose my code.. didnt show it in code, since im quite sure its not the error

Comment: `(*v).LineContent[100] = {""};` ===> `(*v).LineContent[0] = 0;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 v->LineContent[100]
```

is a `char`, which you are trying to initialize as though it were an array / `char *`.

If you already have a `v`,

```
memset(v, 0, sizeof(struct Vector));
```

will zero it (you'll have to `#include <string.h>`).

Writing

```
struct Vector new_vector = {0};
```

declares `new_vector` and initializes all its contents to `\0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{}` to specify the value of individual elements of the array (in this case, `charts) or, as this is a special case, use`""`for the string (a null-terminated sequence of`charts) to initialize it with.  What you wrote was a combination of the two.